# preg_match-PHP: How to check the first 2 digit is in list

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My pattern:
`^([((01|02|35|27|09|38|12|32|21|28|26|36|08|20|24|04|34|23|31|07|16|11|18|14|03|22|37|25|06|30|13|19|10|05|29|15|17|33)(\d{7}))]{9}|(\d{12}))$`

In picture below, `91` isn't in list `01|02|35|27|09|38|12|32|21|28|26|36|08|20|24|04|34|23|31|07|16|11|18|14|03|22|37|25|06|30|13|19|10|05|29|15|17|33` but it still return.

How can I correct it?

[image: PHP live Regex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire regex says: "Find 9 of any characters out of 0-9, parentheses, braces or the pipe character - alternatively find 12 digits"

With that it should be fairly obvious what you've done wrong.

Try this regex instead:

```
^(?:(?:01|02|35|.....|33)\d{10}|\d{12})$
```

Comment: After search on google, I found that `(?:)` is non-capturing group but can you give me more detail information about it?

Answer (score 1):

You have put the whole first section of your regex in a character class (the square brackets, everything between `[` and `]`. You don't need / want a character class as now you are only matching on length (all numbers are included in your char class).

So you can probably use something like (untested):

```
^((?:01|02|35|27|09|38|12|32|21|28|26|36|08|20|24|04|34|23|31|07|16|11|18|14|03|22|37|25|06|30|13|19|10|05|29|15|17|33)(?:\d{7}))|(\d{12})$
```

This should return all numbers of 12 characters (second section) or all numbers of 9 characters starting with the supplied sequences. If that is what you need...

Comment: But it'll return result having 2 digit two

Answer (score 0):

Just checking the first two characters isn't something I would use regular expressions for:

```
$valid = ['01', '02', '35', '27', '09', '38', ...];

if (in_array(substr($str, 0, 2), $valid)) {
    // continue validation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Kollink, I finally founded pattern that worked perfectly for me:

`^(?:(?:01|02|35|27|09|38|12|32|21|28|26|36|08|20|24|04|34|23|31|07|16|11|18|14|03|22|37|25|06|30|13|19|10|05|29|15|17|33)\d{7}|\d{12})$`

Answer (score 0):

since you have all numbers from 01 to 38 in your alternation, you can use this:

```
^(?:(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[0-8])\d{7}|\d{12})$
```